# How to populate database with Cyrillic text

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to populate database with Cyrillic text

```
namespace :db do
  task :populate => :environment do
    Word.create(:word=>"mid-brown",:definition=>"бледно-коричневый")
    ...
  end
end
```

But when I tried to run the migration I've got error - `"invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)"`

I'm using SQLite database

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added `# encoding: UTF-8` string to the beginning of `populate.rake` file